# Test performance of two stuffs, which flags should I use (with gcc) ? -O0, -O2, or -g?

Tags: optimization, gcc

When I write a routine to test the performance of two stuffs,  which optimization flags should I use? -O0, -O2, or -g ?

Comment: Think about it. Do you figure ***maybe*** people will need to know what compiler or whatever you're talking about? ;-) This style of flag is common to several.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder People like released software, so I choose -O2. Thanks.

Comment: @ user: You seem to be missing the point, but at least you added "with gcc" to the title of the question. (Hint: *That's what tags are for*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the performance of your code using each of the settings.  Ideally the larger the number -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, implies better performance as there is more/better optimization, but that is not always the case.

Likewise depending on how your code is written some of it may be removed in a way that you didnt expect from the language or the compiler or both.  So not only do you need to test the performance of your code, you need to actually test the program generated from your code to see that it does what you think it does.

There is definitely not one optimization setting that provides the best performance for any code that can be compiled by that compiler.  You have to test the settings and compiler on a particular system to verify that for that system the code does indeed run faster.  How you test that performance is filled with many traps and other error producing problems that you can easily misunderstand the results.  So you have to be careful in how you test your performance.

For gcc folks usually say -O3 is risky to use and -O2 is the best performance/safe.  And for the most part that is the case -O2 is used enough to get many bugs flushed out.  -O2 does not always produce the fastest code but it generally produces faster code that -O0 and -O1.  Use of debuggers can defeat the optimization or remove it all together, so never test for performance with a debugger based build or using a debugger.  Test on the system as the user would use the system, if the user uses a debugger when they run your program then test that way, otherwise dont.

Answer (score 0):

In GCC `-O0` disables compiler code optimizations at all. `-g` adds debugging info to executable so you can use debugger.

If you want to enable speed optimizations use flags `-O1` or `-O2`. See `man gcc(1)` for more information.

If you want to measure performance of your code use [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) such as valgrind or gprof.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you care about performance you should definitely use **`-O3`**. Why give away potential optimisations?

And yes, there’s a small but measurable difference between `-O2` and `-O3`.

`-g` is not an optimisation flag but it can prevent optimisations so it must be disabled for representative benchmarks.

Comment: `O3` isn't necessarily better than `O2` for gcc as I understand it. O3 does aggressive inlining that can harm locality and decrease performance. Hence always a good idea to check both and see what gives better performance.

Comment: @Voo Like I said, there are benchmarks. While `-O3` may, in pathological cases, be slower than `-O2`, it generally is faster or at least as fast. Inlining in particular normally shouldn’t decrease performance since the optimiser doesn’t inline “stupidly”, it still uses heuristics to determine whether the execution speed would benefit from the inlining.